# C# Trying to find the RobloxPlayerBeta

Tags: c#

Here is my code: I am trying to find the roblox PlayerBeta but its not working
I am not the best in coding but I found out how to find it but cant implent it right into the code

( EDIT ) The program works if I use the PID but that changes everytime I open up a new RobloxPlayerBeta ! so I cannot use that

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Memory;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    namespace ForceField
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            Mem MemLib = new Mem();

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses().Any((p) =>                                                                                                                                         p.ProcessName.Contains("RobloxPlayerBeta")))
        {
            int robloxPid = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("RobloxPlayerBeta").FirstOrDefault().Id;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(robloxPid);
        MemLib.writeMemory("0x184C3A98", "string", "PlsNoBan       ");
        Console.WriteLine(MemLib.readString("0x184C3A98"));

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You could iterate over running processes to find its exact name. Maybe the process name is different then you think.

Comment: Thanks for the fast comment I will look into this!

Comment: Its called RobloxPlayerBeta.exe I dont think I need to add the .exe to the code do I ?

Comment: I posted what I mean as answer

Answer (score 0):

Omg I am stupid.. xD

I needed to do MemLib.OpenGameProcess(robloxPid)